# Is the Polished Silver Sword better or the Troll Bludgeon in Candy Box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

The sword has 7 attack power with medium attack speed, but the bludgeon has 12-16 attack power with slower attack speed.

Answer (score 1):

I have found high damage, low attack speed weapons to work best for me, but generally, the newest weapon you unlock will be the best. In this case, the bludgeon has higher average dps.